# Owl Carousel Displaying Multiple Items on Mobile

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

I am developing a site and to display some testimonials, I am using owl carousel to display them. Right now on desktop everything looks fine and it's flawless.

However, on mobile, instead of one review being displayed horizontally, for whatever reason 4 reviews are being displayed vertically.

In my js I have specified `items: 1`, but mobile doesnt seem to be complying. I also tried

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #owl-client-reviews .review p {
      width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

to see if I could change the width on mobile display.

Here is my code:

**html (there are 10 total items in the carousel)**

```
  <div id="owl-client-reviews" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <div class="review">
           <p>
             "client review"
            </p>
            <br>
       <h4><span class="name">Client</span>  <span class="review">Review</span> </h4>
   </div>
```

**css**

```
 #clients-reviews .review p{
    font-family: 'PT Serif Caption', serif;
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 20px;
}

#clients-reviews .review span.name span.post{
    color: #ed1f24;
}

#clients-reviews .owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-nav [class*=owl-] {
    background: transparent;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid  #fed136;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 14px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #owl-client-reviews .review p {
      width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#owl-client-reviews").owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    autoHeight: false,
    autoHeightClass: 'owl-height',
    dots: false,
    navigation: true,
    navigationText:[
        "<i class='fa fa-angle-left fa-2x' style='color:black;'></i>",
        "<i class='fa fa-angle-right fa-2x' style='color:black;'></i>"
    ]
 });
});
```

Does anyone see something that I am doing wrong? I'm not sure why it's not displaying only 1 item on mobile/tablet. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/one.html - you are missing that option and you don't need the css.

Comment: @Christina thank you, that worked! If you want to put that as the answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the JavaScript owlCarousel option `singleItem:true`. Like so:

```
 $("#owl-client-reviews").owlCarousel({
     singleItem:true,
     items: 1,
     loop: true,
     autoHeight: false,
     autoHeightClass: 'owl-height',
     dots: false,
     navigation: true,
     navigationText:[
    "<i class='fa fa-angle-left fa-2x' style='color:black;'></i>",
    "<i class='fa fa-angle-right fa-2x' style='color:black;'></i>"
]
```

});

Adding singleItem forces the carousel to show just one container at a time.